# Can't figure out how to get the # of rows in a table in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is the question that i'm supposed to answer:

5. Write a script that uses dynamic SQL to return a single column that represents the number of rows in the first table in the current database. The script should automatically choose the table that appears first alphabetically, and it should exclude tables named dtproperties and sysdiagrams. Name the table TotalTable Where Table is the chose table name.

**Hint, use the sys.tables catalog view

Here Is the code that I have so far:

```
    USE MyGuitarShop;

    DECLARE @MyRowCount int;
    SET @MyRowCount = @@ROWCOUNT;

    SELECT TOP 1 sys.tables.name AS TableName, @MyRowCount AS #OfRows
    FROM sys.tables
    WHERE name NOT LIKE 'dtproperties' AND name NOT LIKE 'sysdiagrams'
    ORDER BY sys.tables.name;
```

I have figured out how to get the first table in the selected database alphabetically but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to count the number of rows.  My book isn't being very helpful and I can't seem to find any help any place else.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean Microsoft Sql Server 2012?

Comment: Yes Microsoft SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 0):

`@@ROWCOUNT` is only valid after an operation.

```
DECLARE @TABLENAME NVARCHAR(MAX) = (SELECT TOP 1 sys.tables.name AS TableName
    FROM sys.tables
    WHERE name NOT IN ('dtproperties', 'sysdiagrams')
    ORDER BY sys.tables.name ASC)

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS [Total' + @TABLENAME + '] FROM [' + @TABLENAME + ']'

EXEC(@SQL)
```